# Buildbot configuration error

Tags: buildbot

I have installed buildbot master and slave and when i am running the slave after starting the master this is my master script for a build name simplebuild.

```
c = BuildmasterConfig = {}
c['status'] = []

from buildbot.status import html
from buildbot.status.web import authz, auth

authz_cfg=authz.Authz(
   auth=auth.BasicAuth([("slave1","slave1")]),
    gracefulShutdown = False,
    forceBuild = 'auth', 
    forceAllBuilds = False,
    pingBuilder = False,
    stopBuild = False,
    stopAllBuilds = False,
    cancelPendingBuild = False,
)

c['status'].append(html.WebStatus(http_port=8010, authz=authz_cfg))

from buildbot.process.factory import BuildFactory
from buildbot.steps.source import SVN
from buildbot.steps.shell import ShellCommand

qmake = ShellCommand(name = "qmake",
command = ["qmake"],
haltOnFailure = True,
description = "qmake")

makeclean = ShellCommand(name = "make clean",
command = ["make", "clean"],
haltOnFailure = True,
description = "make clean")

checkout = SVN(baseURL = "file:///home/aguerofire/buildbottestsetup/codeRepo/",
mode = "update",
username = "pawan",
password = "pawan",
haltOnFailure = True )

makeall = ShellCommand(name = "make all",
command = ["make", "all"],
haltOnFailure = True,
description = "make all")

f_simplebuild = BuildFactory()
f_simplebuild.addStep(checkout)
f_simplebuild.addStep(qmake)
f_simplebuild.addStep(makeclean)
f_simplebuild.addStep(makeall)

from buildbot.buildslave import BuildSlave
c['slaves'] = [
    BuildSlave('slave1', 'slave1'),
]

c['slavePortnum'] = 13333


from buildbot.config import BuilderConfig

c['builders'] = [
BuilderConfig(name = "simplebuild", slavenames = ['slave1'], factory = f_simplebuild)
]


from buildbot.schedulers.basic import SingleBranchScheduler
from buildbot.changes import filter
trunkchanged = SingleBranchScheduler(name = "trunkchanged",
change_filter = filter.ChangeFilter(branch = 'master'),
treeStableTimer = 10,
builderNames = ["simplebuild"])
c['schedulers'] = [ trunkchanged ]



from buildbot.changes.svnpoller import SVNPoller
svnpoller = SVNPoller(svnurl = "file:///home/aguerofire/buildbottestsetup/codeRepo/",
svnuser = "pawan",
svnpasswd = "pawan",
pollinterval = 20,
split_file =  None)
c['change_source'] = svnpoller
```

After running this script when i check at browser the status of the build then i am not getting any status of the build.

[image: Console view of build bot]

detail inside the waterfall view is
[image: Waterfall run detail]

1. My first question is where actual build is performed at master's end or slave's end ?
2. What can be the problem in the configuring of buildbot as i have made an error in the commit and was trying to find out weather it will be shown in the waterfall display...but again no error and the same screen as coming in the console view and waterfall view ?

Comment: There is a force build tab in the gui of buildbot it helps a lot to get the result of build steps. so finally configured.

Answer (score 0):

1. Builds are run on a slave, master just manages schedulers, builders and slaves.
2. It seems that builds are not run. As for your second screenshot, it shows change info, but not build info. What does your "builders" tab show?